# add class in child after clone

Tags: jquery, clone, jquery-select2

i want to addClass in child after clone. i want to add class select2 because when i clone select2 too, its not responding.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  addBarang();
});

function addBarang() {
  var new_barang = $(".hidden_input").find(".barang_in").clone().addClass("barang_in_clone");
  $(".target_clone:last").append(new_barang);
  //        $(".barang_in_clone:has(select)").addClass("select2");
}

$('body').on('click', '.btn_kurangi_barang', function() {
  $(this).closest('.barang_in_clone').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="hidden_input" style="display: none">
    <div class="barang_in">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Kode Hanca</label>
      <select name="id_vendor_detail" class="form-control" required="">
        <option value="">- PILIH -</option>
        <option value="1">- Orange -</option>
        <option value="2">- Pink -</option>
        <option value="3">- Red -</option>

      </select>
      <button onclick="addBarang()" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="tambah vendor" class="btn btn-info btn-flat btn-xs pull-left btn_tambah_vendor"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add</button>
      <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="kurangi barang" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-xs pull-right btn_kurangi_barang"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='target_clone'>
  </div>

</body>
```

how to addclass `select2` in `select` ?

//dummy text : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at lectus orci. Quisque maximus hendrerit consequat. Donec blandit facilisis est. Integer ac massa vitae ante vulputate sagittis nec at nisl. Cras sit amet sem nec metus sodales eleifend a ac nulla. Duis porta nisl in erat aliquet hendrerit. Integer mollis non odio et pellentesque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse cursus fringilla sem, facilisis malesuada orci varius in. Nullam tristique nisi sed sem mattis, a finibus magna mollis. Fusce erat sem, semper ac vulputate sit amet, imperdiet sagittis ex

Comment: Try this please

var new_barang = $(".hidden_input").find(".barang_in").clone();
new_barang.addClass("barang_in_clone");
$(".target_clone:last").append(new_barang);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$(".barang_in_clone select").addClass("select2");` selector you can able to add class in select of cloned HTML.

Please check below snippet for better understanding.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  addBarang();
});

function addBarang() {
  var new_barang = $(".hidden_input").find(".barang_in").clone().addClass("barang_in_clone");
  $(".target_clone:last").append(new_barang); 
  $(".barang_in_clone select").addClass("select2");
  $(".select2").select2();
}

$('body').on('click', '.btn_kurangi_barang', function() {
  $(this).closest('.barang_in_clone').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="hidden_input" style="display: none">
    <div class="barang_in">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Kode Hanca</label>
      <select name="id_vendor_detail" class="form-control" required="">
        <option value="">- PILIH -</option>
        <option value="1">- Orange -</option>
        <option value="2">- Pink -</option>
        <option value="3">- Red -</option>

      </select>
      <button onclick="addBarang()" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="tambah vendor" class="btn btn-info btn-flat btn-xs pull-left btn_tambah_vendor"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add</button>
      <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="kurangi barang" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-xs pull-right btn_kurangi_barang"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='target_clone'>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: its work and class `select2` is added. but why plugin `select2` not working ? i know `select2` have a problem when `clone()` how to fix it in my code ?

Comment: Have you written $('.select2').select2(); after select2 class has been applied in cloned HTML?

Comment: Ok but it should be right after the clone. Please look in to the snippet.

Comment: when don't clone, and display in class `hidden_input` `block` and i added `select2`. its work

Comment: Please check the updated snippet I have applied the select2 in it.

Comment: yeah, its work. `$(".select2").select2();` i put in index file, why it not working ?

Comment: You should have to put it after the cloned element as well. The index file one will work for the pre loaded element only. For newly added element you have to apply it after cloned as done in the snippet.

Comment: Rahul , would you help me once again with select ? i have jsfiddle proble with select [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5bjzt4n/)

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan I shown your new question. You want to assign the selected value of the select to the hidden input?

Answer (score 0):

Instead using

```
var new_barang = $(".hidden_input").find(".barang_in").clone().addClass("barang_in_clone");
```

Try this

```
var new_barang = $(".hidden_input").find(".barang_in").clone();
new_barang.addClass("barang_in_clone");
$(".target_clone:last").append(new_barang);
```

It will work :-)